# How to batch fetch all partition offsets of one Kafka topic in one shot? (0.10.x Kafka client)

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I am upgrading our product to use latest Kafka client 0.10.2. The legacy codes are using Kafka client 0.8.1 which using BlockingChannel to batch fetch offset for all the partitions of multiple topics.

When using latest 0.10.2 client, I don't want let the code to touch Zookeeper anymore. However I didn't find any function in KafkaConsumer which can batch fetch offsets for all the partitions for one topic.

For each of the topic, we have more than 100 partitions, I am afraid that the performance will be bad if I call KafkaConsumer.committed(TopicPartition topicPartition) many times to fetch the offset one by one for each of the partition.

Is there any other alternative of achieving this?

Comment: I found there is a ConsumerCoordinator.fetchCommittedOffsets() which I can use, however it is not exposed. Any idea?

Comment: The records returned by `poll` already include their offsets. You could get them by invoking ConsumerRecord.offset(). Is it what you want?

Comment: Thanks @amenthystic! However my consumer is not invoking the poll() function and we are using Sparking streaming Kafka lib to invoke the Kafka client API. My code is only using the consumer to maintain the consumer group reading offset.  And poll() can not return offsets for all the partitions in one batch either.

Comment: You could get some ConsumerRecords wrapped into RDDs, right? Calling ConsumerRecord.offset() could you return you the offset. See https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-kafka-0-10-integration.html#obtaining-offsets.

Comment: @amethystic, our application is maintaining the Kafka topic offsets ourselves. We fetch the offsets before even creating the Spark DStream, and then using the offset to create the Spark Stream. Currently I've managed to resolve the issue as I see there is an private member coordinator in KafkaConsumer which can fetchCommittedOffsets for batch. Do you know why it is private? Is there any potential risk to use this API by changing its permission to public?

Comment: The standard way to fetch offsets from Kafka is to construct an OffsetFetch request and send it to the coordinator. Please see the request format at https://kafka.apache.org/protocol#The_Messages_Offsets

Comment: KafkaConsumer exposes a method `committed` which could also be used to retrieve the offsets. See https://kafka.apache.org/0102/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/KafkaConsumer.html#committed(org.apache.kafka.common.TopicPartition)

Comment: @amethystic, the existing API commited() exposed in the KafkaConsumer can only fetch offsets for single partition. What I am seeking for is to batch fetch offsets for multiple partitions at the same time. Then we can avoid sending multiple OffsetFetch requests which impact the performance.

Comment: Not sure if you have checked the codes in KafkaConsumer, the fetchCommittedOffsets() API is internally invoke the coordinator by sending a batch Fetching request. I am quite curious why they don't expose it.

Comment: yes, it's not exposed. I am afraid you have to create an OffsetFetch with all the partitions you are interested in and send it to the coordinator manually, such as `new OffsetFetchRequest.Builder(this.groupId, new ArrayList<>(partitions)).setVersion(2).build()`